# Problem loading range_slices in Cassandra

Tags: range, cassandra, thrift

I'm having just a little bit of trouble getting data out of Cassandra. The main problem is this exception:

```
ERROR 15:45:07,037 Internal error processing get_range_slices
java.lang.AssertionError: (162293240116362681726824838407749997815,35552186147124906726154103286687761342]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getRangeSlice(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1251)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.getRangeSlice(StorageProxy.java:428)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.get_range_slices(CassandraServer.java:513)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$get_range_slices.process(Cassandra.java:2868)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor.process(Cassandra.java:2555)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

So what do I do? I use `describe_ring` to get the topology of the network, then I ask each of the nodes in the network `describe_splits` which gives me the tokens I should use to fetch the ranges, and then I just start asking for them, making sure that I set the `start_token` and `end_token` on the keyranges.

Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like a bug. mind show us some code?

Comment: Of course :-) http://pastebin.com/dsdMGZjW It is part of a Pig LoadFunc. I later load the splits with this code: http://pastebin.com/yGT5umYm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug fixed for 0.6.9 and 0.7rc2.

Comment: Very good! I should of course have added what version this happens on.